# How to include all necessary packages (or library) into archive for Python code to work

Tags: python, archive

I have a Python code that I have to send to my teacher. The issue is that I import the following packages :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as date
import ephem
```

I would like to create an archive .tar with my Python code inside but also all the necessary packages (`numpy, matplotlib, datetime` and the important `ephem`) to make the Python code running. Indeed, I am not sure that my teacher has all these packages installed on his computer.

Is it possible to perform this action in order to, for my teacher, unzip archive .tar and just do "python source.py" to get the code running without missing packages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way would probably be to distribute a `requirements.txt` file that the `pip` command understands. i.e. you'd create the file containing:

```
numpy
matplotlib
ephem
```

and these would be installed by doing:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

which would cause those packages to be installed.  Note that you can include [version numbers and other specifications](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers) in the requirements file if needed.

Note that we do this because installing packages like `numpy` can be non-trivial due to dependencies like BLAS which can be awkward to get configured under arbitrary OSs.